# Sub category loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following controller that retrieves "subcategories", and then loops through each subcategory, grabbing and storing what I've termed "circles" into an instance variable

```
  def show
    @sub_categories = Category.where(:parent => params[:id])
    @sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
      i = 1
      @circles[i] = Circle.where(:category_id => sub_cat.id)    
      i++
    end
  end
```

This is outputting an error.  I'm coming from PHP and don't know how to do this properly.

```
categories_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected kEND
```

Comment: ps. I know I could just do @circles = Circle.all, just trying to write a more efficient query

Comment: Please tell us what the error is and give us a back trace and tell us what line it happens on, or else it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you should just use a [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
@circles = Circle.joins(:categories).where(:categories => { :parent_id => params[:id] })
```

To address the code you've written: adding to an array in Ruby is done with [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C). So you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
@circles = []
@sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
  sub_cat.circles.each do |circle| # assumes Category has_many :circles
    @circles << circle
  end
end
```

But you'd better use `joins` to do it in one query, like I show above.

Update based on pastebin:

There is no need to set `@circles`.

This is what your view should look like:

```
<% @sub_categories.each do |sub_cat| %>
  <div class="circle">
    <header>
      <h3 data-toggle="collapse" href="#<%= dom_id(sub_cat) %>-collapse"><%=sub_cat.name %></h3>
      <ul id="<%= dom_id(sub_cat) %>-collapse" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <li class="list-shadow"></li>

        <% sub_cat.circles.each do |circle| %>
          <li><%= link_to circle.title, circle, :remote => true, :method => 'get' %></li>
        <% end %>

      </ul>
    </header>
  </div><!--.circle-->
<% end %>
```

To prevent the [N+1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), you have to do this in your controller:

```
@sub_categories = Category.includes(:circles).where(:parent => params[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you x 2, now I know how to add to arrays in Ruby.  I was getting an error with your first block of code, but I'll try to get that to work as it seems like that'd be the more correct way of accomplishing this

Comment: it's in my view, so I need to clean that up.  

I'm not exactly sure if this will work as in my view I'm looping through the sub_categories, and displaying any circles that are in those sub categories

Comment: correction: of course it won't, because I needed that instance variable @sub_categories to perform the sub category loop

Comment: In that case isn't it enough to just set `@sub_categories`? I don't think you need `@circles`. You can do the same nested iteration in your view as I show above.

Comment: This is my view:
http://pastebin.com/8KwmS8BZ

please excuse my class nomenclature

Comment: Like I said, you don't need `@circles`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your updated answer works perfect.  Forgive me for my lack of knowledge, but why are there circles within sub_cat (sub_cat.circles.each do |circle|)?

Comment: Because in your `Category` model you have `has_many :circles`. Check [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for the basics of ActiveRecord relations.

Answer (score 0):

**each** is a iterator

since u r collecting the **circles**  for the selected subcategories, u can simply write it as

```
@subcategories.collect{|sc| Circle.where(:category_id => sc.id) }
```

it will return u the array of circles.

Comment: The problem with this code is that `Circle.where` doesn't return a `Circle` object, but a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So you won't get an array of circles, but an array of `ActiveRecord::Relation`s.